# Katalon - export recorded test script to java/junit

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, katalon-studio

Is there an option to export recorded test script to Java/JUuit(similar to slenium IDE) in Katalon studio? Because the application I'm working on is compatible only with IE; so I couldn't use selenuim IDE. so I'm forced to find someother tools to play/record sessions.

Appreciate your help in advance! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

As of version 4.8 Katalon Studio does not support export test cases to other frameworks. But if you want more control on your project, you can modify test cases directy in the [Script Mode using Groovy/Java](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/tutorials/test-design/create-test-case-script-mode/). It is also possible to [import 3rd party Java libraries](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/tutorials/import-java-library/) to your project if need be.

Answer (score 5):

After creating the test case with some steps, we could view the script and adjusting it, for examples: https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Test+Case+Script+View

From here, we could add more codes to handle our testing flows.

However, since the code uses some Katalon libraries, so it might not posible to copy the script and run somewhere else.

Comment: May I know the reason why you want to export the scripts? It is good to use all with Katalon studio then.

Comment: Because I would like to have more control over the code; I'm using spring/cucumber/JUnit framework for my testing automation. I would like to export the recorded session like what slenium does; so that I can customize the code as I wanted to be more maintainable.

Comment: I got your point now. I think if you are using Spring, Cucumer and Junit, then POM will fit with your setup and Selenium IDE is not very useful.

Answer (score 2):

you can export code into java/ python using Katalon browser plugin. Just import existing test case recording into the plugin and click on "export" option.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can export it Java (Junit, TestNg), python, C#, Ruby.

Download the chrome pluging

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder-selenium/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid

Follow the guide screen

[image]

[image]

[image]

Create a Maven Java project, create a new Test class file and copy paste the code and run the project to test the browser test.

Done !

Answer (score 1):

You can record your test and export in the following language and framework:

- C#
- Java
- Python
- Robot Framework
- Ruby

It is an extension for chrome like Selenium IDE 
you can find it [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder-selenium/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver is what would be needed, not Selenium IDE.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).